# How to setup a k8s dotnet core api with replicas and ingress as load balancer on on-premise?

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to create a simple solution on my local server running Windows Server 2016 in which I want to deploy a dotnet core API with 5 replicas into k8s. I want to have an Ingress service set up such that it acts as a load balancer between the replicas of my app.

So far I got nothing.

Could anyone provide me a template that could accomplish that?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a running Kubernetes cluster?

If not, then I would start from that. There are many ways to achieve that. If you are beginner you might want to try [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) or bootstrap your cluster with [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/).

Once you achieve that you will need to use [deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)  to have your .net app running in Kubernetes.

To expose your deployment you use [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). In minikube this is very easy as you just have to enable it via `minikube addons`. In `kubeadm` you will have [deploy](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#bare-metal) ingress controller that will support your ingress object.

There are many documents and information about how to start with deploying .NET application on the web, such as:

- [Andrew Lock | Net escapades](https://andrewlock.net/deploying-asp-net-core-applications-to-kubernetes-part-1-an-introduction-to-kubernetes/)
- [Running ASP.NET Applications in Kubernetes — A Detailed Step By Step
  Approach](https://medium.com/@bterkaly/running-asp-net-applications-in-kubernetes-a-detailed-step-by-step-approach-96c98f273d1a)

Once you try something out please come back with some more specific issues. Stackoverflow is not that type of place for such a general questions.

Comment: Good & detailed explanation! But as you yourself have pointed out "_Stackoverflow is not that type of place for such a general questions_", so you should urge OP to give more debugging details or point OP to appropriate Stack-exchange site in the comments instead.

Comment: I agree that in some way you are right but looking at the `So far I got nothing` sentence I don't know if there is much to ask for. I more than happy to help and I hope that this kind "nugde" will help OP moving with its goal.